# Attempt to connect to SQL Server causes ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, sql-server-2005

```
import java.sql.*;

public class MysqlConnect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "\\host/context/";
        String dbName = "theDatabaseName";
        String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver ";
        String userName = "theUserName";
        String password = "thePassword";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to the database");
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing problem while the running this code.

I have already downloaded the SQL Server driver (sqljdbc), set it in the class path and copied it into the java/lib directory, but still I am getting the same result: `ClassNotFoundException`.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: please be specific on what is the 'problem' you are facing? Any errors/exceptions/traces?

Comment: Please mention the error details too.

Comment: i have made all the suitable  changes said by u people but still getting the same result  and getting the error  file not found exception-> java.lang.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: Can you copy-paste the exception stacktrace?

Comment: ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at MysqlConnect.main(MysqlConnect.java:13)

Comment: now my problem regarding the class path is resolved but now i am getting new error         java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver:\\x
eon-s5\LDF RAID (G)\himanshu_ci
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at MysqlConnect.main(MysqlConnect.java:14)        plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' class in your classpath.

Make sure you have following jars in your CLASSPATH: Msbase.jar, Msutil.jar, Mssqlserver.jar

More details here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100

Comment: do an `echo %CLASSPATH%` on commandline and see if the output contains the required jars.

Comment: i have entered .;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;D:\app\himanshu.jain\product\11.2.0\client_3\jdk\bin;D:\sql\sqljdbc4.jar;\D:\sql\sqljdbc.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\himanshu.jain\Desktop\jakarta-jmeter-2.5\lib\mssqlserver.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\himanshu.jain\Desktop\jakarta-jmeter-2.5\lib\msbase.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\himanshu.jain\Desktop\jakarta-jmeter-2.5\lib\msutil.jar;         BUT IT IS SHOWING ONLY   .;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;    I DONT KNOW WHY

Comment: now my problem regarding the class path is resolved but now i am getting new error         java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver:\\x
eon-s5\LDF RAID (G)\himanshu_ci
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at MysqlConnect.main(MysqlConnect.java:14)        plz help me

Comment: Your url should be `jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;DatabaseName=dbname`

Answer (score 1):

Please check the JDBC URL. The one mentioned by you  `\\xeon-s5/LDF RAID (G)/` does not seem to be correct URL. A Typical URL will look like `jdbc:sqlserver://neptune.acme.com:1433`. Check out [this](http://www.razorsql.com/docs/help_sqlserver.html) further. Here [how to](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100) connect to SQL server from java.

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing space at the end of your class name.

```
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver "
```

should most likely be

```
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Have you added sqljdbc.jar to the build path for the project?

Comment: ya i have added sqljdbc.jar to the class path

Comment: on the classpath or on the project build path?  Are you running this from the command line or from an IDE?

Comment: can you copy and paste your entire command line string to your question?

Comment: D:\>javac MysqlConnect.java

D:\>java MysqlConnect